# cardinality of a basis for a topology

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Suppose X is a space of cardinality $\le \kappa$. I would like to claim that any topology on X has a basis of cardinality $\le \kappa$. Intuitively it's true since even the discrete topology has such basis but i can't prove or find a counter-example...

Thanks!

Comment: The minimal cardinality of a basis for a space $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is called its *weight*, $w(X)$. In fact we can have $w(X, \mathcal{T}) < |X|$, for example the usual topology on $\Bbb R$. The Stone-Cech compactification $\beta\omega$ of the discrete space $\omega$ is another — see [this post](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/weight-of-a-topological-space/). However, As @PaulPlummer's answer states, in general it's not true that $w(X, \mathcal{T})\le |X|$.

Comment: Let $F$ be a free ultra-filter on $N$, the natural numbers. Then $F\cup \{\phi\}$ is a topology  on $N$ with no countable base. In General Topology ,by Engelking, he gives an example of a $T_1, T_3$ topology on $N$ that has no countable base.

Comment: The best you can do is $w(X) \le 2^{|X|}$, I believe for Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma  $w(X) \leq 2^{|X|}$ is always true since that is the max cardinality of a topology (topology $\tau \subseteq 2^{X}$), so taking the topology to be the base gives an upper bound.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not appear to be true. Let me recommend a wonderful website [$\pi$-Base](http://topology.pi-base.org) where you can search for topologies having certain properties. In particular I searched for a countable space which is not second countable (no countable base) [here](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Countable%2B%7ESecond%20Countable). It gives various examples.